# Multiple SignalR (websocket) connections vs. A single connection with multiple hubs

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, microservices, signalr-hub

[Architecture Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV83F.png)

Suppose we're building an SPA (Single Page Application) which depends on a couple of independent back-end systems. Basically a Microservice-ish implementation of SignalR-hubs.

Each of these back-end systems expose a separate SignalR endpoint with a separate set of hubs;
The separation of these hubs across different back-end systems is intentional in design (again, because of microservice-ish considerations).

Basically, a single browser session to the app will have to maintain a separate SignalR-connection for every endpoint on which we depend and connections will be managed (opened and closed) on demand by the relevant components.

A flow that I can think of for an example would be:

> A request initiates a booking request -> booking request is dependent on n number of services in order to be "completed" (whether succeeded or failed) -> due to asynchronous communication between those services, the client will receive a "booking id" for reference and will be notified on booking process through the relevant "booking-hub" that handles certain events from different services -> leaving the "booking component" will cause the hub to disconnect.

**This leads us to the following questions**:

- In an architecture overview, is it a right assumption that also a SignalR hub(s) should be completely decoupled?
- Are there any best practices regarding the usage of "websockets" in combination of a microservice-ish architecture?
- Are there any limitations (beside the fact that some browsers might limit the number of websocket connections) in manner of scaling?

Answer (score 1):

> In an architecture overview, is it a right assumption that also a SignalR hub(s) should be completely decoupled?

Many resources and what I have seen in my office implementations is that it is a better approach have a single Hub (core) that can be used from your services.

> Are there any best practices regarding the usage of "websockets" in combination of a microservice-ish architecture?

It depends of how you want to handle your connection.

> Are there any limitations (beside the fact that some browsers might limit the number of websocket connections) in manner of scaling?

Webscokets can have only 10 connections at once.

PS: About the connection, in the old SignalR version ([@aspnet/signalr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/)) the re-connections where managed by SignalR but in [the new version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/) you need to do that by yourself.

Comment: @peter thank you very much for your comment but the information you've provided wasn't really helpful since it still doesn't really answer the questions I've presented.

Comment: @talboren hello, yes this was more like generic answer. Hope someone will help you more specifically.